# Regresson Discontinuity - design questions

Tags: econometrics, regression-discontinuity

I am considering a regression discontinuity design (RD) where the "treatment" has a definite sorting rule (below the threshold, you are not fined - above the threshold, you are fined). The outcome I am considering is how much you are fined the FOLLOWING year. There are 4 options: 1) remain without a fine, 2) go from no fine to fined, 3) fined less than you were the previous year, or 4) fined more than you were the previous. While I have listed these as categorical, I have the continuous amount of the fine as well.

Here are my questions: 1.) I have never seen a "longitudinal" RD design where the treatment is at a time period before the outcome. Are there any methodological issues with this approach? 2.) Assuming this approach is valid, how best should I model the outcome given the multiple possibilities?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/3100/regression-discontinuity-questions).